# Run C# code at specific time

Tags: c#, .net, timer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Execute function at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681465/c-execute-function-at-specific-time)

I want to run certain function at certain time.I tried Timer control.it's not working. My question is:How can I run a function every day at the 19:00 in C#?
Is there any way to check the time and have a Timer object?

Timer code:

```
int Interval(TimeSpan gorevZamani)
{
    if ((gorevZamani - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay).TotalMilliseconds > 0.0)
        return (int)(gorevZamani - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay).TotalMilliseconds;
    else
        return (int)((gorevZamani - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay).Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)).TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: If you want to run the code every day at 19:00, the easiest solution might be to create a [Scheduled Task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task) in your OS. Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the question set as possible duplicate: [C# Execute function at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681465/c-execute-function-at-specific-time) people suggest to use either [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) or windows Task Scheduler.

Both options could eventually serve the purpose but I believe, as I suggested already few times in similar previous questions, Windows Task Scheduler is better because you no code anything for it and let Windows do the scheduling for you and you focus only on the real business case of your application, which is what Windows cannot do for you, then rely on existing technologies to glue things together and don't have to debug or reinvent what has been done and is available for you anyway.

Comment: +1 for suggesting Quarts.NET it's great thing though

Answer (score 1):

Use a scheduled task. A good way to do this is the `at` command, documented on MSDN [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565).