# How to execute specified task at the specified time

Tags: c#

I am new to C# but java has method to execute specified task at the specified time so using c# how it doing

```
Timer t=new Timer();
TimerTask task1 =new TimerTask()           

t.schedule(task1, 3000);
```

Comment: add a timer with callback and check for desired condition and execute what you want

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Execute function at specific time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681465/c-sharp-execute-function-at-specific-time)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a complete tutorial of how timer works in C# here : http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer

In Short:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Timers;

public static class TimerExample // In App_Code folder
{
    static Timer _timer; // From System.Timers
    static List<DateTime> _l; // Stores timer results
    public static List<DateTime> DateList // Gets the results
    {
        get
        {
            if (_l == null) // Lazily initialize the timer
            {
                Start(); // Start the timer
            }
            return _l; // Return the list of dates
        }
    }
    static void Start()
    {
        _l = new List<DateTime>(); // Allocate the list
        _timer = new Timer(3000); // Set up the timer for 3 seconds
        //
        // Type "_timer.Elapsed += " and press tab twice.
        //
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Enabled = true; // Enable it
    }
    static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _l.Add(DateTime.Now); // Add date on each timer event
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, @mssb. Did this answer your question? If so, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the "tick"-mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: C# not provide new Timer(3000); like constructor

Comment: .net does have that timer constructor. Include all his code in your class. he is using System.Timers.Timer @mssb

Answer (score 4):

Using [`Anonymous Methods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and `Object Initializer`:

```
var timer = new Timer { Interval = 5000 };
timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(@"Hello world!");
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample:

```
public class Timer1
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        // Set the Interval to 5 seconds.
        aTimer.Interval=5000;
        aTimer.Enabled=true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while(Console.Read()!='q');
    }

    // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is raised.
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {

        public void TimerTask(object state)
        {
            //Do your task
            Console.WriteLine("oops");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var program = new Program();
            var timer = new Timer(program.TimerTask, 
                                  null, 
                                  3000, 
                                  Timeout.Infinite);
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }
}
```