# How to automate a windows form application without windows scheduler?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to make an application which automatically moves files from source folder to destination folder on specified "time"(2 different times in a day). Once entered, this app should run daily. I have made a form application which moves file perfectly on button click. I need to implement this without any button click interaction.

Scheduling using Windows Task Scheduler is not an option for me.

Comment: `Task.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromDay(1);`
something like this in a loop or a timer I guess?

Comment: A simple timer that Ticks every minute and checks whether `DateTime.Now` is in the desired *range*. It's not clear if you want your app to run non-stop or you are referring to a sort of *laucher*. You can always use the `AT` command and a batch file.

Comment: "this app should run daily" and "without scheduler" is very confusing requirement. What exactly you expect to start your app daily?

Comment: If you explain **why** you can't use Windows Task Scheduler to start your app, we can avoid giving answers that you can't use for the exact same reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Execute function at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681465/c-sharp-execute-function-at-specific-time)

Comment: This task is not build for a `process` (windows form). you need to build a windows `service` that has a timer mechanism that will schedule your task. also, a processes can be terminated when the machine user is disconnected and a windows service will keep running when no user is authenticated. here is  a starting point:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I have achieved exactly that by creating a windows service project and put all the button click logic in a class library.
For scheduling the service i used Quartz.Net so that it can triggers the job/service at given interval.

You can find more about Quarts.Net [here](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/quick-start.html).

Please do note that you need administrative access to install and run your windows service.