# How do I run a windows service in every one hour?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

I've created a windows service and install it successfully and I've created some code inside that to send an email, if date and time are matched.

Now I want to run that service for every one hour to check that the date and time are matched or not.

I don't understand how do i do that?

Please help.

Comment: Windows service is supposed to keep on running all the time. You just need to check for the date, idle for a minute or so if the time isn't yet reached.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Service that runs Periodically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498498/windows-service-that-runs-periodically)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows services are supposed to run continuously - If you just need it to "wake up" once an hour why not to make it a Scheduled Task instead?

---

With Scheduled Tasks all you need is to compile your code and then you can "Create Task", direct it to your exe and set when to run.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

With System.Timers.Timer you have more options, where System.Threading.Timer is a lightweight timer. I would recommend you to use System.Timers.Timer

set the tmrExecutor.Interval to interval for how much time you want to run you send email and interval is in milisecond

as per your requirment is for every one hour is 3600000 milli seconds

```
Timer tmrExecutor = new Timer();

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
  tmrExecutor.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(tmrExecutor_Elapsed); // adding Event
  tmrExecutor.Interval = 3600000; // Set your time here 
  tmrExecutor.Enabled = true;
  tmrExecutor.Start();
}

private void tmrExecutor_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  //Do your Sending email work here
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
  tmrExecutor.Enabled = false;
}
```